# How come I get a timed-out when I try to download something off my own domain?

Tags: python, django

```
def download(source_url):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
    agents = ['Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)','Microsoft Internet Explorer/4.0b1 (Windows 95)','Opera/8.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)']
    ree = urllib2.Request(source_url)
    ree.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(ree)
    htmlSource = resp.read()
    return htmlSource


url = "http://myIP/details/?id=4"
result_html = download(url)
```

It shouldn't time out...even with the 10 second timeout..

Comment: Verify you can connect there in your browser.  Try performing "telnet myIP 80" from a command prompt and then issuing `GET /details?id=4 HTTP/1.1`.  What happens?

Comment: What's serving at `http://myIP/details/`? What do you see if you go there with a browser? Where's the django in this code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail if you're running the development server, since it's single-threaded and it's busy serving the original request. Use mod_wsgi or strap on something like [CherryPy](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/25/serving-django-cherrypy/) if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "your own domain", are you hitting it from inside a NAT firewall?

Something like this?

123.1.2.3 (public myIP) <- NAT gateway -> 192.168.1.5 (private IP of server) <-->  192.168.1.10 (you)

Many firewalls don't allow an internal address to access an external interface without DNS rewrite. DNS rewrite causes the firewall to intercept your DNS lookup and rewrite the resulting public IP with the private IP.